# How to use ArrayUtils for array of objects, it doesn't delete the content of an array

Tags: java, arrays

How to delete the content of an array of objects. If there is other ways to delete a content of an array of objects , please do share.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class Testing {

  public static void deleteItem(ItemTracker[] listItems) {
    System.out.println("Which item you want to delete? ");
    for(int i=0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Quantity")) {
                // Some Code
            } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Something"){
                ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i); //  This is the part where it should delete .. but it doesnt delete. 
            } 
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the down votes on the 3 correct answers...

Comment: @CoverosGene To be honest, the downvotes are correct, because every anwser (except Ilyas answer) forgot to mention, that calling `ArrayUtils.remove()` "alone" won't help him here. He also need to change his method to return the new array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);
```

to

```
listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);
```

As you can see in the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.Object[],%20int%29), the method does not change the argument `listItems`, rather it returns a new array with the remaining elements.

**Edit**

You also need to change your deletion method to

```
public static ItemTracker[] deleteItem(ItemTracker[] listItems) {
    //..
}
```

So you could return the new array with the remaining elements.

Comment: What will this assignment do?

Comment: @zvdh This is the correct way of using of `ArrayUtils`, but you're right, it won't help him much, if OP doesn't change his `deleteItem` method.

Comment: @Tom Try and it still didnt work, is there any difference whether you put void or no?

Comment: @NaufalYahaya It is mandatory to use `ItemTracker[]` as the return type and to call `return listItems` in your method. The "original" array referenced by `listItems` won't be changed by your delete method, therefore you have to return the new array created by `ArrayUtils.remove()` to pass it the calling method.

Comment: @Tom I tried to print the output, it did delete, but after it goes out of the function, the value somehow is still there. I'm really confused right now. What actually does the ArrayUtils.remove() does behind the scene?. and how do i save the value and put it in a new array?

Comment: @NaufalYahaya Let's say you call the method `deleteItem` with `array1`. In it `ArrayUtils.remove` creates a new array, `array2`, and returns it. You can print the `array2` and the desired item is gone, but it is still available in `array1`. The method that called `deleteItem` only has access to `array1`. To "give" him `array2` you'll have to return it from the `deleteItem` method. For example by calling `return listItems` (with my suggested change) or by `return ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);`. The calling method need something like `items = deleteItem(items)` to receive the new array.

Comment: @Tom I tried to put ***items = deleteItem(items)*** but it doesnt work .. see link [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e8592bcab8b22b2398e it still showing the real array

Comment: @NaufalYahaya That is correct. Can you show me the updated `deleteItem` method, please?

Comment: @Tom sure here it is [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/204dae30728aa2b555d5

Comment: @NaufalYahaya Is `input` set to `something`? Have you tried to use a debugger to see, if the `else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Something")` branch is entered and how `listItems` changes? And you have an additional `}` in that code.

Comment: @Tom Oh I may have accidentally added '}' and by the way check again, you will get the idea what i want to achieve [link] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71a7cb491584b05fda2f

Comment: @NaufalYahaya You're always deleting the first array element if the user input something special. This code looks also ok, so it is necessary to use a debugger here to see that actual happens and if the `listItems` array changes correctly.

Comment: @Tom Let say there are 4 objects in the array, and the user input a value and it matches a variable inside one of the object, it supposed to delete that specific object , thats what i want to achieve,  but couldn't find any perfect solution for it.

Comment: @NaufalYahaya You mean `listItems.getxyz.equals(input)`? But this is not part of this question. What about the current problem (new array not passed to the calling method)?

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to explain the instruction before deleting the item, anyway the new array is not passed to the calling method, so you have any idea how to solve it? since I couldn't think of anything right now.

Comment: @NaufalYahaya Yes, I have an idea: use a debugger. Your code snippets are ok, so there is no other way to find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Store the resulting array.

*It won't change the original array object.*

```
listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);
```

**Edit:** But for using this method you need the change to return type of your method

```
public static ItemTracker[] deleteItem(ItemTracker[] listItems){
    System.out.println("Which item you want to delete? ");
    for(int i=0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Quantity")) {
                // Some Code
            } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Something"){
                listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i); //  This is the part where it should delete .. but it doesnt delete. 
            } 
            break;
        }
      return listItems;
      }
```

Comment: This assignment is absolutely useless - it will change reference of local method `listItems` variable to new array, meanwhile a method consumer will still have reference to the unmodified array, won't it?

Comment: @zvdh I think you are confused about references. Try this code in your compiler.

`String x = "abc";  x = x + "def"`; 

Are you ok with this example.

Comment: Do you realize, that this assignment won't take effect for initial array?

Comment: @zvdh  Initial array would be unmodified. If you want to check then store it in `temp` before remove() call and after method call print `temp`. From my understanding, it should not change.

Comment: Yes I know it won't change the initial array.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari `zvdh` tries to say you, that the `listItems` array that was passed as the method argument won't be changed for the calling method. "He" still has the same array with the deleted item after calling `deleteItem(listItems);`.

Comment: The same question, as for @TAsk, what is the purpose of implemented method if it doesn't take effect on passed array?

Comment: @Tom, yes, it's exactly what I mean

Comment: `int x[] ={1,2,3};
x = ArrayUtils.remove(x, 0);
System.out.print(x.length);` Tell me value of `x.length` @zvdh

Comment: @DeepakTiwari `ItemTracker[] items = { ... }; deleteItem(items);`. Tell us `items.length`. It is the same as before `deleteItem(items)`, because the new array was not returned to the calling method. The intial array `items` remains unchanged.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari, what are trying to explain me? The problem of your approach, that in fact it will not change initial array *at all*, you don't modify it, you reassign reference to this array to another, new array.

Comment: @zvdh in his case it won't help. He is returning `void`. Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari Tried it and it still didnt work, is there any difference whether it is void or not?

Comment: @NaufalYahaya, there is big difference. In short, you're not able to pass to method with such signature as you wrote in question array with size `n` and modify it to `n-1` size array. There is two options: either return new array (you need change type of method from `void` to `ItemTracker[]`) or just remove specified item, but it means that one element of your array will be `null`.

Comment: @zvdh I'm trying to implement the first option, but it doesnt work, the updated version [link] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/204dae30728aa2b555d5 and the calling method [link] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e8592bcab8b22b2398e

Comment: @NaufalYahaya, `for` statement is not correct in `deleteItem` method, try to remove `break` and use `return` instead of reaasignment to `listItems`

Comment: @zvdh I tried that as well, but it still returning the original array [link] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c8e6fdaac13811d12a51

Comment: @NaufalYahaya, possibly there is another bug, I have no idea. We gave you advice how to resolve exact problem. Now it's your turn, try to debug method. This bunch of code is not self-sufficient and I'm sure that the current problem isn't associated with original question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In your case usage of `ArrayUtils` is incorrect and redundant. You can delete element in next way:

```
// ...  
listItems[i] = null;
// array will looks like [o1, o2, null, o3, o4, ...]
// ...
```

There is no other way without changing method's return type

Comment: This does not delete the entry. Also this can cause other problems if "someone" iterate over that array without checking for null elements.

Comment: @Tom There is no other way in his case. Correct solution is to return new array, instead of remove elements from existing one

Comment: This is indeed a good point. I've updated my answer to mention that. Your version should work to.

Comment: This answer is correct. Remembering, that arrays in Java have fixed size, we are not able just to remove one of it's elements, we need to return new array of `initial size - 1`. And it's not possible cause this method doesn't return value.

Answer (score 1):

> **[`ArrayUtils.remove`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.Object[],%20int%29)**
>
> *This method returns a **new array** with the same elements of the input
>   array except the element on the specified position. The component type
>   of the returned array is always the same as that of the input array.*

So,you should use it like this

```
listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i);
```

***NOTE***

- Here we have assign the returned array to current `listItem`.
- As this method does not change the actual array but returns the changed array after removal same as `#replace` method works for `String`.

> ***YES***. I agree with [`zvdh`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782379/zvdh) I have missed the purpose of your method
>   because I was more concentrated on removal of element.Sorry for that!!
>    *as this will not actually change the `listItem` and you need to `return` the new array which contains the change.*

Comment: What will this assignment do?

Comment: In this case, what is the purpose of this method?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional libraries, with temporary list:

```
Element arrayToRemoveFrom[];
Element toRemove; // should be known already

ArrayList<Element> tmpList = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(arrayToRemoveFrom));
tmpList.remove(toRemove);
// any other code processing and removing elements
arrayToRemoveFrom = tmpList.toArray(new Arrays[tmlList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Arrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      double[] numbers = {6.0, 4.4, 1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};
      java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);

      System.out.print("Ascending order= ");
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");

      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("Decending order= ");
      for (int i = numbers.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");

     }

}
```

This solution only displays in reverse order, but it can be changed to reorder the array using the same loop.