# Trying to use ArrayUtils.removeElement

Tags: java, libraries

I have added the correct library - common net 3.6 to NetBeans and my project.
However, there's still an error shown.

I'm using there imports;

```
import java.lang.Object;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
```

Here's the included library.
[included library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3tuQ.png)

I watched a tutorial so I know I added this library correctly, yet I still can't use ArrayUtils.

What may be the problem?

Comment: "there's still an error shown" what error?

Comment: Do you use Maven or you manually deal with dependencies?You don't tell us the error sir , but I bet that has something to do with a dependency (apache Arraylist here)

Comment: You don't need to import anything from the `java.lang.*` package, it's imported implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid this hassle is using ArrayList instead of Array in the first place.

But you can refer to 
[How to use ArrayUtils for array of objects, it doesnt deleted the content of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360865/how-to-use-arrayutils-for-array-of-objects-it-doesnt-deleted-the-content-of-an)

its already been answered here.